# IOS app distribution over-the-air : error when download can't connect to domain

Tags: ios, iphone, nginx, in-house-distribution

we are currently deploying a new app over the air on IOS and Android, android no problem to download an apk on internet with a simple link, but on IOS we are currently on a issue when we try to access to the server from the download link.
"Cannot connect to "domain.com" "

I don't know what is wrong : the plist is good and ipa too, i checked all links with my browser.

The MIME TYPES for plist and ipa are :
plist : text/xml
ipa : application/octet-stream

The https:// port is customized to 8443
https://domain.com:8443/webapp/app.html

download link :

```
<p><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://domain.com:8443/webapp/app.plist">DownLoad Iphone APP</a></p>
```

plist file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>https://domain.com:8443/webapp/app.ipa</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>com.app.myapp</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>1.3</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>myapp</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My web server is behind a reverse proxy nginx that work well (there is an translation 8443 to 8080 between reverse proxy and webserver) etc.

The log of reverse proxy show this when i try to download the app, strangly i get an 503 error, but all browser like chrome which got the .ipa has an HTTP response 200 OK, but when i click on download on my iphone i get an 503 error on nginx log :

```
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http script copy: "^M
"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http script copy: ""
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http script copy: ""
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "User-Agent: itunesstored/1.0 iOS/7.1.1 model/iPhone3,1 build/11D201 (4; dt:27)"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Accept-Language: fr"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Accept: */*"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header:
"GET /webapp/app.plist HTTP/1.1^M
Connection: upgrade^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
User-Agent: itunesstored/1.0 iOS/7.1.1 model/iPhone3,1 build/11D201 (4; dt:27)^M
Accept-Language: fr^M
Accept: */*^M
^M
"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http cleanup add: 0000000002149C20
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 get rr peer, try: 1
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 socket 14
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 epoll add connection: fd:14 ev:80000005
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 connect to 10.xx.xx.xxx:8080, fd:14 #18846
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream connect: -2
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 posix_memalign: 00000000020D2C20:128 @16
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 event timer add: 14: 90000:1400249192473
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http finalize request: -4, "/webapp/app.plist?" a:1, c:2
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http request count:2 blk:0
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http run request: "/webapp/app.plist?"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/webapp/app.plist"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream request: "/webapp/app.plist?"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream send request handler
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream send request
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 chain writer buf fl:1 s:231
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 chain writer in: 0000000002149C58
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 writev: 231
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 event timer del: 14: 1400249192473
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 event timer add: 14: 90000:1400249192474
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream request: "/webapp/app.plist?"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http upstream process header
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 malloc: 000000000219B170:4096
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 recv: fd:14 1038 of 4096
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy status 503 "503 Service Unavailable"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 785"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header: "Pragma: no-cache"
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 http proxy header done
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 finalize http upstream request: 503
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 finalize http proxy request
2014/05/16 16:05:02 [debug] 7217#0: *18845 free rr peer 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solved this issue, i need to pass in full HTTPS with the backend, the iphone detect insecure content and cancel the download.

Comment: I'm trying with Firebase, which uses GCS buckets, and it's still not working.